# Python's subprocess unable to run script in a network location on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a Windows machine. In my Python program, I am using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to perform a system call to an executable. The executable I am trying to run is in a network location, e.g.

`\\mycompanyname\\internal\\...\\myscript.pl`

I'm using the function as follows:

```
subprocess.run(['\\mycompanyname\\internal\\...\\myscript.pl'])
```

and I always get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

If I copy and paste the exact same command in a cmd shell, it works fine. How can I get subprocess to correctly resolve a file at a network location?

Comment: Add `r` before opening `'` so that double backslashes are literal double backslashes, instead of single backslashes (but escaped)

Comment: Posted with some more explanation for anyone searching it in the future. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses escape sequences with backslash. Thus, double backslash in a normal string = escaped (single) backslash.

To use the string literally, omitting any escaping, use raw string - denoted by `r` just before opening quotes:

```
subprocess.run([r'\\mycompanyname\\internal\\...\\myscript.pl'])
```